# How to respect .call = FALSE in stop within sub function in R

Tags: r

This is a simple question about how to provide clean error messages from sub functions in R.

Usually, adding `call. = FALSE` to `stop` will not show the surrounding code to the user when it displays an error message from a function:

```
sub_function <- function() {
  please <- "don't show this code"
  stop("testing stop call equals false", call. = FALSE) 
}
sub_function()

Error: testing stop call equals false
Called from: sub_function()
```

However, if you put it inside another function can call it with `mapply`, it will not respect that setting:

```
stop_test <- function(pkgs) {
  sub_function <- function(pkg_name) {
  please <- "don't show this code"
  if (pkg_name == "ahah!") stop("testing stop call equals false", call. = FALSE) 
  }
  mapply(sub_function, pkgs)
}
stop_test(c("dplyr", "ahah!"))

Error: testing stop call equals false
Called from: (function (pkg_name) 
{
  please <- "don't show this code"
  if (pkg_name == "ahah!") 
    stop("testing stop call equals false", call. = FALSE)
})(dots[[1L]][[2L]])
```

How can I get R to only display my error message from sub function calls like this second example?

Comment: you could wrap the call to sub_function in try_catch. catch the error with another stop that itself sets .call. or you could change the behavior of sub_function so that it doesn't error, and only deploy the error in stop_test.

Comment: Can you please show what you see for each of the calls? I'm pretty much seeing the same output.

Comment: I think you messed up the outputs